# Clock script not working, when the seconds reach to 10, 30 or 60, the specific text("half minute passed.. etc") doesnt print. The rest works perfectly

Tags: python, database

```
import datetime
import time

now = datetime.datetime.now()

while True:
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    seconds = (now.strftime("%S"))
    print(seconds)

if (seconds) == 10:
    print("ten seconds has passed!")

if seconds == 30:
    print("half minute has passed!")

if seconds == 00:
    print("one minute has passed!")

time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: This is probably a copy/paste issue - the indentation of the if statements should be within the "while"  range - just add extra tab .. and convert seconds to integers:int(now.strftime("%S")).

Answer (score 0):

`seconds` is a string, you need to convert it to int before you compare it to int

`seconds = int(now.strftime("%S"))`
Although this is not needed, you can just use `now.seconds`

Answer (score 0):

The indentation is wrong, the if statements and sleep will never be executed.

Also, use now.second instead of now.strftime("%S").

`````python
import datetime
import time

while True:
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    seconds = now.second
    print(seconds)
    
    if seconds == 10:
        print("ten seconds has passed!")

    if seconds == 30:
        print("half minute has passed!")

    if seconds == 00:
        print("one minute has passed!")

    time.sleep(1)
````
`````

Comment: thanks men, im not very good when it comes to programming in python, i used to write c# scripts, but the logic in python is a bit different

Answer (score 0):

When you use now.strftime("%S"), it returns the seconds in string format, thus envelope it in an int() bracket to convert it into an integer so that it compares integers in your if statement. Move your time.sleep(1) up so that it doesnt print out multiples per second, only 1. The code below should work for you.

```
import datetime
import time

now = datetime.datetime.now()

while True:
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    seconds = int(now.strftime("%S"))
    time.sleep(1)
    print(seconds)

    if (seconds) == 10:
        print("ten seconds has passed!")

    if seconds == 30:
        print("half minute has passed!")

    if seconds == 00:
        print("one minute has passed!")
```